# Importing and changing variables from another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

Okay...

I have searched and searched looking for an answer that directly answers my question, but have had no success. My problem is pretty straight forward and I honestly thought there would have been a more direct answer out there. Please keep in mind I am still relatively new to the language, and am still learning.

*So I will use `fileA` and `fileB` as my two files, and `x` as my example variable.* Variable `x` is contained in `fileB`. How do I go about importing variable `x` into `fileA`, **then** change `x` to another value via `raw_input`, **and then** have the variable `x` update in `fileB` with the new value?

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I would sure like to think so. I am using python 2.7.11, thank you in advanced.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @PeterWood So basically... I have a file that I am using for player stats (fileB) which has a variable that tracks the players level. I want to make a way for me to use raw_input to change that variable to debug the program and change the level when I need to so that I can check various levels after I edit them.

Comment: That sounds like a config file? In FileA import FileB then create a function called modifyParam(fileB.player.level), FileB player.level = 5

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If the "variable" you're referring to is an mutable value, what you're asking for will just work.

fileB:

```
my_variable = ["a list with a string in it"]
```

fileA:

```
from fileB import my_variable  # import the value
my_variable.append("and another string")
```

After `fileA` has been loaded `fileB.my_variable` will have two values in it.

But, that only works for mutable values. If the variable is immutable, the code in `fileA` can't change it in place, and so you'll have issues. There's no way to directly fix that, but there are many ways to work around the issue and still get at what you want.

The easiest will simply be to use `import fileB` instead of `from fileB import my_variable`. This lets you anything in `fileB`'s namespace, just by using a name like `fileB.whatever`. You can rebind things in the namespace to your heart's content:

fileB:

```
my_variable = 1    # something immutable this time
```

fileA:

```
import fileB
fileB.my_variable = 2   # change the value in fileB's namespace
```

That is probably the simplest approach.

Another solution would be to put the immutable variable inside a mutable container, and then modify the container, rather than the variable. For instance, if the string `"a list with a string in it"` was the value we wanted to change my the first example, we could simply assign a new value to `my_variable[0]` (rather than appending).

A common way to do this is to put values into a dictionary, list or even in a class (or a mutable instance of one). Then you can import the container object and mutate it to change the value you care about.

Comment: Very concise and precise answer. Thank you!

Comment: This should be a wrong answer. Because, it sets a variable inside another python file but after it is executed completely.

Comment: @FarzadAmirjavid: that's the only way to change a variable in another module. If you could somehow enter your value before the module ran, it would get overwritten by whatever the module sets it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean constant variable, in 90% of situations, it means bad architecture of a program, because it may be implemented easier.

One of a possible way could be:

create some functions in both of files with input parameter and execute them and play with value.

for example:

fileA.py

```
from fileB import testB
TEST_VAL = 5

def testA(val):
    TEST_VAL += 10
    result = testB(TEST_VAL)
    # play with changed TEST_VAL
```

fileB.py

```
def testB(val):
    # do something
    return val ** 2
```