# Problem updating variable in backend code after user input in askfloat() in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a tkinter interface that displays calculation and includes parameters for the user to modify the parameters. I am trying to get the modified parameters to get implemented in the backend code. So basically the calculations take into account the user input.

As suggested in several stackoverflow posts, I have separated the backend code, the parameters file and the front end code.

What I want to achieve is a way to let the user input a parameter that take the place of the initial value of this parameter in the parameter file and then use this new value on for backend code calculation. Currently, the parameters can be entered fine but they dont update the backend code

The code I currently have runs with no error, however, the new parameter value inputed does not get saved and used in calculations.

here is what my update parameter code look like:

```
        cout_stockage = StringVar()

        def get_parameters():

            cout_stockage.set(holding_cost)

        def get_cout_stockage():

            s = simpledialog.askfloat("modifier parametre", 'modifier cost')
            parametres.holding_cost = s
            cout_stockage.set(parametres.holding_cost)
            ee3 = Entry(LeftFrame1, textvariable=cout_stockage)
            ee3.grid(row=0, column=1)


        ee = Entry(LeftFrame1, textvariable=cout_stockage)
        ee.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

my parameter file looks like this:

```
def variables():
    global holding_cost

holding_cost = 0.15
```

finally the last file looks like this:

```
df['holding_cost'] = parametres.holding_cost
```

following [Importing and changing variables from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913078/importing-and-changing-variables-from-another-file) I have tried including the name of the file in the change in the tkinter box in order to update the actual value but its still does not make the trick, the backend code does not get modified. I was wondering if anybody has any help to provide on the issue.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've asked a question. You've explained what you're doing, but haven't explained what you need help with. What does "still make make the trick" mean?

Comment: I have updated my question to explain what the issue, lmk if i can explain some more