# Overwrite a global variable outside of the script

Tags: python, design-patterns, global-variables

When I am calling the function func in a Jupyter notebook or another script, how can I overwrite the global variable **`alpha`** below outside of the script? (I don't want to pass the alpha as the function argument)

```
# script.py
alpha = 10

def func(a, b):
    return a * alpha + b
```

For example, the user defines his own alpha in a csv file and have the following code in Jupyter notebook or another script. Is it possible to overwrite on the one defined in script.py?

```
# Jupyter notebook
from script import func

parameters = pd.read_csv('parameters')
alpha = parameters[0]

print(func(10, 20))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This might help. It's already answered here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34913678/5838671

```
import script
script.alpha = parameters[0]

print(script.func(10, 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import script
parameters = pd.read_csv('parameters')
script.alpha = parameters[0]
```

You can have that in addition to what you already have, or you can remove `from script import func` and refer to `func` as `script.func`