# Python : access to a variable from an other module is only given as a reference

Tags: python, reference, pytest

I am working on writing the tests for a project that has a massive technical debt and am running into limitations of my understanding as to how python references variables

Here is the very simplified example :

```
main.py
src/
  __init__.py
  foo.py
  variables.py
tests/
  __init__.py
  unit_test.py
main.py
```

the `__init__.py` and `main.py` files are empty

foo.py

```
from src.variables import GLOBAL_VARIABLE


class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print(f"foo :{id(GLOBAL_VARIABLE)}")
        if GLOBAL_VARIABLE:
            return 1
        return 2
```

variables.py

```
GLOBAL_VARIABLE = False
print(f"\norig:{id(GLOBAL_VARIABLE)}")
```

unit_test.py

```
import src.variables
from src.foo import Foo


def testFoo():
    src.variables.GLOBAL_VARIABLE = True
    print(f"\ntest:{id(src.variables.GLOBAL_VARIABLE)}")
    foo = Foo()
    assert foo.bar() == 1
```

I am attempting to change the value of a variable contained in the src/variables.py file in order to run some tests but I can only get a copy rather than the variable itself

The output is as follows ( simply running pytest with no configuration nor arguments ) :

```
orig:140734094465928
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

tests\unit_test.py
test:140734094465896
foo :140734094465928
```

I cannot seem to get access to the variable itself from the test module, only a copy. I have attempted different imports for the tests but I am consistently getting a variable that does not have the same id and the simply fails

How can I change the value of GLOBAL_VARIABLE ?

There are solutions that I have attempted such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913078/importing-and-changing-variables-from-another-file) but was not able to change the value of my boolean ( the difference seems to be that I am importing from an other module ? )

As a bit of context I cannot change the tested code ( would like to ), only the tests, so I cannot implement better coding practices on the tested code

Comment: _How can I change the value of GLOBAL_VARIABLE ?_ Have you tried `src.variables.GLOBAL_VARIABLE = something`?

Comment: The problem is that `from src.variables import GLOBAL_VARIABLE` creates *another variable* (**not a new object**). It is essentially equivalent to `import src.variables; GLOBAL_VARIABLE = src.variables.GLOBAL_VARIABLE`, so if you modify `src.variables.GLOBAL_VARIABLE = whatever`, then it won't get updated

Comment: *however*, you could use `import src.foo` in your tests and modify `src.foo.GLOBAL_VARIABLE = whatever`

Comment: Note, "but I can only get a copy rather than the variable itself" is not what is actually happening.

Comment: "but I am consistently getting a variable that does not have the same id " **variables don't have Id's, *objects* do**.  Variables refer to objects. `True` and `False` are different objects, they will always have different id's.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the observations I’ll experiment with it. At the very least it gives me a direction to looks into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `unit_test.py` actually modifies the `variables.GLOBAL_VARIABLE`, but the `foo.py` has a copy of it.

You could either update the `unit_test.py` so that it imports the copy from `foo.py`:

```py
# unit_test.py
import src.foo
def testFoo():
    src.foo.GLOBAL_VARIABLE = True
    print(f"\ntest:{id(src.foo.GLOBAL_VARIABLE)}")
    f = src.foo.Foo()
    assert f.bar() == 1
```

Or you could update the `foo.py` so that it also does `import variables` instead of `from variables import GLOBAL_VARIABLE`.

```py
# foo.py
import src.variables
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print(f"foo:{id(src.variables.GLOBAL_VARIABLE)}")
        if src.variables.GLOBAL_VARIABLE:
            return 1
        return 2
```

I am not saying that importing and changing global variables from other modules is a good idea for production codes, but for testing, this is probably fine.